# Quali sono gli errori di sintassi in "permangono le tratte saltate o in ritardo"?

Tags: grammar

Sapreste indicarmi se "*Permangono le tratte saltate o in ritardo*", frase scritta nell'edizione odierna del quotidiano *[La Stampa](http://www.lastampa.it/2013/11/12/italia/cronache/maltempo-due-morti-nelle-marche-freddo-e-vento-sferzano-tutta-litalia-zQBoaAUIIB9dKDG4OZrPqI/pagina.html)*, è un frammento intellegibile, o sintatticamente corretto?

> **Permangono le tratte saltate o in ritardo** per i collegamenti navali, a causa delle condizioni del mare.

Certo, dal contesto si comprende che il giornalista voglia riferirsi alla permanenza delle condizioni che impediscono il regolare servizio di collegamento marittimo fra l'Italia e la Sardegna, ma è mai possibile che si possa scrivere questa informazione in quel modo?

Quali sono, if any, gli errori di sintassi? Più precisamente, per esempio, possono "le tratte saltate", e che quindi sono già "saltate", permanere "saltate" nel tempo?

Comment: Come frase è terrificante, anche se non so se si possa dire che ci siano dei "veri" errori di sintassi...

Answer (score 6):

Secondo me la frase è errata.

Le tratte non possono essere in ritardo o peggio ancora saltate, lo si capisce sostituendo tratte con un sinonimo.

> Permangono i **percorsi** saltati o in ritardo per i collegamenti navali,
>   a causa delle condizioni del mare.

Possono saltare (o essere in ritardo) i collegamenti, le corse, i treni, i traghetti, ma non le strade, le rotte, i percorsi o i binari (a meno di non usare la dinamite).

Può saltare la corrente (o per metonimia la linea elettrica), ma non salta il palo della luce.

Comment: Concordo completamente, +1.

Comment: (si scherza) questa immagine della luce che salta dipinge una dinamica differente: http://dl2.glitter-graphics.net/pub/2876/2876092naobr8wuxo.gif

Answer (score 1):

"Permanere" in quel caso vuol dire "continuare ad essere, durare"; significa che per i collegamenti navali, alcune "corse" non vengono effettuate o subiscono ritardi. Vuol dire che, supponendo ci sia una nave od un battello ogni 20 minuti, potrebbe succedere che il prossimo battello arrivi dopo 40 minuti, o che ci sia un battello dopo 30 e 40 minuti.

La frase non ha errori di sintassi, anche se preferirei scrivere "a causa delle condizioni del mare" all'inizio. Si tratta soltanto di mettere enfasi su una diversa parte del frase, che nel caso riportato è "permangono", la parte che per chi legge la notizia è probabilmente più importante.

Volendo riscrivere la frase, scriverei "le tratte saltate o in ritardo permangono per i collegamenti navali, a causa delle condizioni del mare" oppure "a causa delle condizioni del mare, le tratte saltate o in ritardo permangono per i collegamenti navali".
Usando uno stile più giornalistico, più adatto ad un titolo, userei "ancora ritardi e tratte saltate per i collegamenti navali". In questo caso, non si tratta di una frase completa, ma con un "ci sono" sotto inteso all'inizio.